# Make the background fixed (stationary)

Tags: html, layout, css

Is there anyway to make the sky/lake background stay still while you scroll?

[Site](http://www.ipalaces.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that site, change this line

```
<div><img src="images/bottom_bg.jpg" width="100%" alt="" /></div>
```

to

```
<div id="foobar"><img src="images/bottom_bg.jpg" width="100%" alt="" /></div>
```

And add the following CSS:

```
<style>
#foobar{ position: fixed; bottom: 0px; width: 100%; }
</style>
```

That should do the work.

Answer (score 13):

In CSS:

```
background-attachment: fixed
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment

Answer (score 3):

Or in shorthand:

```
body {background: url("/images/myimage.png") no-repeat fixed top left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
    background-image:url('lake.jpg'); /* or whatever */
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```